# White residue on hibiscus leaves

Tags: hibiscus

[image]

This white, powdery substance has been forming on my hibiscus plant leaves. Any advice on what it is and how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you are in the world, this may be a heavy giant whitefly infestation, and the white web like deposits are associated with them. If you shake the branches, do insects fly up? If they do, that's what the problem is, see here https://www.hiddenvalleyhibiscus.com/care/whiteflies.htm.

As the infestation is so heavy, it's probably necessary to use an insecticide spray such as Bayer Rose and Flower, but, if you think they are whitefly, check other shrubs to make sure they do not have whitefly as well, even if they look normal.